# Circle packing with static size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement the [D3 pack layout](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md) with static size circle values where I want D3 to take care of just placement but I see the d3 is overriding the provided circle size. I'm not sure how to keep the same size passed from the data. See the below code, in that, when I change the size of the children with label `RAD` from `100` to `5000`, I see the size of other circles are changing, how can I make the layout to render with the exact size which I get from data? please provide me some pointer or jsfiddle

link to codepen - https://codepen.io/navinleon/pen/mxZJWr

Thanks in advance.

```
var w = 1000,
    h = 500;

var data = {
    name: "root",
    children: [{
        label: 'RAD',
        size: 100,
        color: '#c99700'
    }, {
        label: 'BIL',
        size: 100,
        color: '#008ce6'
    }, {
        label: 'EEN',
        size: 100,
        color: '#007377'
    }, {
        label: 'INO',
        size: 100,
        color: '#b4975a'
    }, ]
};

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h);

var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
    .value(function (d) {
        return d.size;
    }).padding(100)
    .size([w, h])
    .nodes(data);

// Get rid of root node
nodes.shift();

canvas.selectAll('circles')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', function (d) {
        return d.r;
    })
    .attr('fill', function (d) {
        return d.color;
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using d3.packSiblings():

There is in fact a convenient method, named `d3.packSiblings`, which seems to be exactly what you need (without any force simulation) to position the nodes.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#packSiblings):

> Packs the specified array of circles, each of which must have a `circle.r` property specifying the circle’s radius.

So, changing the `size` property in your data to `r`, all you need is something like:

```
var packed = d3.packSiblings(data.children);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RAD',
    r: 50,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL',
    r: 75,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN',
    r: 20,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO',
    r: 42,
    color: '#b4975a'
  }, ]
};

var packed = d3.packSiblings(data.children);

var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data.children)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

#### Using a force simulation

You actually **don't want** a circle pack layout. The circle pack layout will necessarily fit all the circles in the area specified by `pack.size` array.

Since you want to set the circles' size yourself and you want D3 to only take care of placement, the most obvious option that comes to my mind is using a *force simulation* instead.

In this proposed solution, we'll set the focus point to the center of the SVG using `forceX` and `forceY`. Then, we'll stop the simulation and run it a given number of times (the less elements you have the less iterations you need):

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();
```

Here are some demos.

First, setting all circles' radiuses to 100:

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RAD',
    size: 100,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL',
    size: 100,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN',
    size: 100,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO',
    size: 100,
    color: '#b4975a'
  }, ]
};

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data.children)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.size
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's reduce the size of 3 circles to 20:

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RAD',
    size: 20,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL',
    size: 100,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN',
    size: 20,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO',
    size: 20,
    color: '#b4975a'
  }, ]
};

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data.children)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.size
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Now all circles with 10 as size:

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RAD',
    size: 10,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL',
    size: 10,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN',
    size: 10,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO',
    size: 10,
    color: '#b4975a'
  }, ]
};

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data.children)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.size
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, let's make one of the circles 5000. The only thing you'll see is the whole SVG as a single color... but this is what you asked for: the circle has a radius of 5000 pixels. Check it:

```js
var w = 500,
  h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
    label: 'RAD',
    size: 5000,
    color: '#c99700'
  }, {
    label: 'BIL',
    size: 100,
    color: '#008ce6'
  }, {
    label: 'EEN',
    size: 100,
    color: '#007377'
  }, {
    label: 'INO',
    size: 100,
    color: '#b4975a'
  }, ]
};

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();

var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data.children)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.size
  })
  .style("fill", function(_, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you Gerardo, can you please explain me about the below code from your sample "var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data.children)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) simulation.tick();"

Comment: And it will be really helpful and if its not too much to ask, can you please give me one more example which has data children inside children? example: {
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "label": "RAD",
      "size": 100,
      "color": "#c99700",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "TATA",
          "size": 100,
          "color": "#A99700"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: That's just the code that sets the simulation. Regarding your second question, if you want to use hierarchical data you'll have to use the circle packing layout, unfortunately no hack available here.

Comment: @NavinLeon I just found a new method, please have a look at the edit.

Comment: thank you @Gerardo Furtado. Do you know what is the difference and advantage between packSiblings and forceSimulation? and why packSiblings is recommended?

Comment: @NavinLeon The force solution is a bit of a hack, since that's not the original purpose of a force directed chart. On the other hand, `d3.packSiblings` is precisely the right tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the attribute 'r' return the size of each data node like this:

```
.attr('r', function (d) {
    return d.size;
})
```

I'm not sure which attribute of the circle you want defined from your size, but you can modify accordingly. Right now, the radii are set as 150, 120, 100

Now your data will change the size of circle. You can try with this data:

```
var data = {
    name: "root",
    children: [{
        label: 'RAD',
        size: 150,
        color: '#c99700'
    }, {
        label: 'BIL',
        size: 120,
        color: '#008ce6'
    }, {
        label: 'EEN',
        size: 100,
        color: '#007377'
    }]
};
```

See codepen: https://codepen.io/andrewgi/pen/xWvNJe